# Background colors matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made this picture with matplotlib. I would like to split the background in two slightly colorfull side with two legends in each of them "mu < mu_{0}" for the left and "\mu > \mu_{0}$ for the right.

Do you know how to do that ?

THanks and regards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.fill` to specify the area of the graph to shade. You can also used `plt.text` to annotate the sections. Here's an example of this for a graph not too dissimilar to yours (symmetric around the y-axis and bounded above by 1 and below by 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(x, np.abs(np.sin(x)))

# Get the left and right extent of the area to shade
LHS, RHS = ax.get_xlim()

# Specify the area to shade as the corners of the square we're interested in
ax.fill([0, RHS, RHS, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], c='C1', alpha=0.3)
ax.fill([0, LHS, LHS, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], c='C2', alpha=0.3)

ax.text(-np.pi/2, 0.4, '$x < 0$')
ax.text(np.pi/2, 0.4, '$x > 0$')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't find a clear exemple on internet how ax.fill([0, RHS, RHS, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], c='C1', alpha=0.3) works. 
I would like to get a square  basis :  [0,0]  _  [1,0] hight : [0,1] _ [1,1]